# Flag dialog on low-score answers appears faded out

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging, css

> #### Related Meta Stack Overflow requests
>
> - [The flag pop up on heavily downvoted answers has grey
>     text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text)
> - [Flag popup in review is translucent for non-hidden ignored
>     tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/flag-popup-in-review-is-translucent-for-non-hidden-ignored-tags)

#### Current status

When you flag an answer that has a very low score (and therefore appears greyed-out), the flag dialog is shown in the same faded-out colors:

[image]

Obviously, that doesn't make sense.

---

#### Desired status

This is what it actually should look like:

[image]

For those implementing, it is probably enough to set the `color` of the whole dialog `div` to `black` (which is what I did in my preview). But you probably know where to look at and there are a couple of other CSS properties to fix here.

Comment: You forgot to darken the "mod flags remaining" I think.

Comment: @Hello71 Yeah I didn't *really* care to make it 100% perfect, that's not my job is it :)

Comment: I think this is something of a known problem that the pop-up incorrectly takes styling from the posting - at [least](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text) [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/flag-popup-in-review-is-translucent-for-non-hidden-ignored-tags) MSO posts exist on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - has been fixed.

As waffles said:

> We were setting "color" on the top level post div, the flag was inheriting it. I changed it so we target .downvoted-answer .post-text
>
> I just change a bunch of style sheets. This should be resloved.
>
> Another bug was lurking ... on many SE 2.0 sites the downvoted styling was overridden. That is also fixed.
>
> If every single stylesheet on all our sites breaks ... it is my fault

*Source:* https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110817/144987