# Flag box is transparent

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag dialog on low-score answers appears faded out](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3016/flag-dialog-on-low-score-answers-appears-faded-out)

[image]

Picture pretty much says it all. Note, my hunch is that this has to do with the fact that the answer was grayed out (at -3) but I have no real idea. Does not occur on other posts that I have seen.

Comment: I think it does have something to do with that, it's a bug.  It transfers the fading from the downvoted answer to the box as well.  After a certain number of downvotes, the answer will fade...

Comment: It's a bug, but they won't care to fix it. It's been raised on MSO a couple of times.